# Working with Unsplash. Cannot assign value of type 'Array<_>' to type 'Any?'

Tags: arrays, swift, type-conversion

Currently, I'm working on processing information I've received from a JSON file, and as it's organized into multiple levels, I need to be able to convert not only the file, but all of its contents into the correct file types. I'm having some issues with this, and I can't find anything for Swift on this issue.

So far, I've tried the methods that are apparent within the code below. I couldn't find much information on alternate methods to do this, and I'm still new to programming, so I haven't been able to do much.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
    if let data = data {
        print("Clear")
        let returnData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

        do {
            let image = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            print(image!["results"])
            var imgl2 = image!["results"]
            imgl2 = imgl2 as! Array
            //imgl2 = imgl2![0]
              //print(imgl2!["color"])
//                var imgl3 = imgl2!["results"]
//                var imgl4 = imgl3!["results"]
//                var imgl5 = imgl4!["results"]
//                var imgl6 = imgl5!["results"]
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    }.resume()
```

What should happen here is that I should be able to convert the JSON's contents into the correct file types. To some extent, this works, and I'm able to obtain the first level of results. However, partway through the process at imgl2 = imgl2 as! Array, I can't convert it to an Array. Instead, I receive the error (Cannot assign value of type 'Array<_>' to type 'Any?'). I'd really like to be able to use the array enclosed, but I can't. After this, there will be several additional levels of content that I will need to sort through in this manner. I've tried looking at the API documentation, but I don't understand the way they've written it (this is Unsplash, by the way), and as such, I've tried this method. How exactly would I go about this?

(For further information, I'm trying to pull out the first image in the results, so that I can then edit it programmatically. I need the URL enclosed in the response to the search query, but the way the documentation is worded is unclear enough, and solutions to this problem so sparse, that I've had to use trial and error to get to where I am. Any insight into how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.)

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot assign value of type 'Array<_>' to type 'Any?

The error tells you that `imgl2` is of type `Any?`, but you're trying to assign it a value of type `Array`. Swift doesn't allow changing the type of a variable after it has been initialized. What you could do is to assign `imgl2 as! Array` to a new variable to avoid this error.

I also suggest you to have a look at `Decodable` protocol to create models corresponding to the JSON structure.